# Accessing and cancelling a periodic timer in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, periodic-task

I am using a periodic timer for fetching data from server. I need to conditionally stop the timer when a bool (`userExpectingTimerBool`) has been set to false and also explicitly stop it by user. After stop, neither the periodic timer `_timer`, nor the last scheduled callback timer `_t` (or `t`) should run.

**I have a fully working code now. But I feel some of it is redundant** and some aspects of periodic timer is still not clear to me after reading documentation. Code is included below.

---

I have four questions:

1. Do I need to stop both `_timer` and `_t` (or `t`) to stop all scheduled tasks?
2. Which timer should I use to display search count (`t.tick`/`_t.tick`/`_timer.tick`)?
3. The callback function is a transient (nameless) method. Is the timer passed as an argument to it (`t`) a persistent or transient object (i.e., its value will be preserved across runs)?
4. What parts of the below code are redundant/can be reduced?

---

**periodic timer with conditional run:**

```
Timer _timer;
Timer _t;

bool userExpectingTimerBool=false;
var timerSearchCount;
var tSearchCount;

_timer = Timer.periodic(
   Duration(seconds: intervalGiven), 
   (Timer t) { 
        _t= t; 
        if (userExpectingTimerBool == false) t.cancel(); 
        tSearchCount=t.tick; 
        _displayResult(); 
   }
); 

timerSearchCount=_timer?.tick;
```

**user-controlled stop timer function:**

```
  void stoptimer(){
    setuserExpectingTimerBool(false);
     if (_t !=null){_t!.cancel();}
     if (_timer !=null){_timer!.cancel();}
     checktimerActive();
  }
```

Comment: you don't need `_t` - it is the same as `_timer`

Comment: @pskink does it also mean `Timer t` is same as `_timer`. If so, can I pass the same `_timer` as argument in the callback function like this: 
`_timer = Timer.periodic ( Duration(seconds: intervalGiven), (_timer) { ... } )`

Comment: *You* don't pass a `Timer` as an argument to the callback function.  The `Timer` invokes the callback and passes itself as the argument.  You can name the `Timer` parameter for your callback function however you want, but naming it `_timer` would be a bad idea since it would shadow the member, and doing something like `_timer = somethingElse;` within the callback would misleadingly assign to the local parameter, not the member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When `Timer.periodic` invokes its callback, it should invoke it with itself as the callback's `Timer` argument.  Therefore `_t` is just an alias for `_timer`, and having both is pointless. (You can verify this for yourself by printing `identityHashCode(timer)` and comparing against `identityHashCode(_timer)`.)
2. See #1.  Does not matter.
3. See #1.  There is a single `Timer` object created by `Timer.periodic`.
4. ```dart
   if (userExpectingTimerBool == false)
   ```

   If `userExpectingTimerBool` is not nullable, then it would be clearer as `if (!userExpectingTimerBool)`. (If you believe that `== false` is more readable, then why not `if ((userExpectingTimerBool == false) == true)` and `if (((userExpectingTimerBool == false) == true) == true)`, etc.) `userExpectingTimerBool` seems unnecessary anyway; if `stoptimer` is called, the `Timer` will be cancelled and prevent additional callbacks.  You therefore shouldn't need to perform an additional cancellation check within the callback.

   ```dart
   if (_timer !=null){_timer!.cancel();}
   ```

   As written, `_timer` is non-nullable, so the null check is unnecessary.  If you intend for `_timer` to be nullable, then you can replace the explicit `if` check with just `_timer?.cancel();`.